# SharePoint 2010 get person or group field display name using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

Am trying to get the Person or Group field(approver) value using REST API in SharePoint2010. 
am able to get the account details but i need the display name of the Approver. 
here is the my code

```
        $.ajax  
    ({ url: siteURL+ "/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/"+ listName +"("+ietmID+")?$select=Name,Approver/Account&$expand=Approver",// list item ID 
         method: "GET",
         headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
         success: function (data)
          {

        var listiteminfo= data.d;  

            var approvers="";
        var approverLenght=listiteminfo.Approver.results;
        //alert(approverLenght.length);
        for (var j = 0; j < approverLenght.length; j++) {
        alert(approverLenght[j].Account);

        }       


             //success(data.d);
          },
        error: function (data)
        {
        alert('error');
       // failure(data.responseJSON.error);
        } 
});
```

Comment: Hi how you authenticate this url in 2010.. any reference please ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please try with below endpoint

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/"+ listName +"("+ietmID+")?$select=Name,Approver/Account,Approver/Name,Approver/UserName&$expand=Approver"
```

Hope it helps you and can find user properties below [link to refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088553/sharepoint-2010-users-groups-over-rest)

```
<m:properties>
<d:ContentTypeID>0x010....</d:ContentTypeID>
<d:Name>Doe, John</d:Name>
<d:Account>ABC\john.doe</d:Account>
<d:WorkEMail>jd@abc.com</d:WorkEMail>
<d:MobilePhone m:null="true" />
<d:AboutMe m:null="true" />
<d:SIPAddress m:null="true" />
<d:IsSiteAdmin m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsSiteAdmin>
<d:Deleted m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:Deleted>
<d:Picture m:null="true" />
<d:Department m:null="true" />
<d:Title m:null="true" />
<d:FirstName>John</d:FirstName>
<d:LastName>Doe</d:LastName>
<d:UserName>John.Doe</d:UserName>
<d:WebSite m:null="true" />
<d:AskMeAbout m:null="true" />
<d:WorkPhone>8885551212</d:WorkPhone>
<d:Office m:null="true" />
<d:Unit m:null="true" />
<d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">2</d:Id>
<d:ContentType>Person</d:ContentType>
<d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-09-27T00:00:19</d:Modified>
<d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2013-10-17T12:13:59</d:Created>
<d:CreatedById m:type="Edm.Int32">3</d:CreatedById>
<d:ModifiedById m:type="Edm.Int32">1073741823</d:ModifiedById>
<d:Owshiddenversion m:type="Edm.Int32">217</d:Owshiddenversion>
<d:Version>1.0</d:Version>
<d:Path>/sites/test/_catalogs/users</d:Path>
</m:properties>
```

`